# Receiving arguments for starting destination of navigation from an FCM notification

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a navigation graph that starts from a specific fragment which takes one argument `startingId`

by default inside my graph I have its value set to 0

up to now I had the backend devs send me notifications that only contained `data` like:

```
"data" : {
    "startingId" : 3
}
```

which would mean that it always triggers my application (even if it is in the background) and I would create a notification with a pending intent that would load my application with the correct parameters

unfortunately the application went cross-platform and now they have to send me FCM messages like so:

```
"notification" : {
    "title_loc_key" : "start_changed"
    "body_loc_key" : "start_changed_body"
    "android_channel_id" : "updates"
}
"data" : {
    "startingId" : 3
}
```

this means that when the user clicks on the notification while my application is in the background, the application will start with a bundle of startingId -> 3 as parameters

but I can't use that bundle in my starting fragment

instead what I do in the fragment is something like this:

```
private val startingId by lazy { activity.intent?.extras?.getValue("startingId")?.toString()?.toIntOrNull()?: 0 }
```

and I have removed the `startingId` argument from my starting fragment

is there a way to create a notification that will pass the "data" payload to my starting destination fragment like I would do with only a "data" json object? or am I stuck with retrieving the value from the activity's intent?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not [passing data to your start destination](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#start)?

Comment: That's what I used to do with my pending intent, unfortunately now the intent is created by the notification and when my app is in the background I can't affect it

Comment: and by that I mean that the data json object is available to my activity but not my starting destination when the app starts from the notification

Comment: I'm confused. The docs I linked to are specifically about doing whatever pre-processing you want at the activity level (i.e., the level that owns the whole `NavHostFragment`), then passing exactly the arguments you want to your start destination. It has nothing to do with PendingIntents or any of that.

Comment: oh so you mean that I could use the activity itself to pass the arguments from the notification, instead of expecting the notification to do the work, I hadn't thought of that, you're right, that should work, thank you